# How to sum the unique keys in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum

I have a bunch of key values in a list:

```
all = [('a' : '87'), ('b': '72'), ('a' : '39'), ('b' : '84')]
```

How can I quickly sum up all of the values that have the same keys?

Output:

```
a = 126
b = 156
```

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary.

Comment: This code is wrong in two ways. (1) Can’t use duplicate keys, it will replace them. (2) You named it `dict`. Congratulations, you just shadowed the name of an important type.

Comment: Sorry but you cannot do that because you can't use duplicate keys (it will replace them). So you maybe should use another type like tuple.

Comment: I was just using dict as an example but when I went back and looked I saw what you were saying about not having duplicates. I switched the data into a list. Can I sum it up from there?

Comment: You posted a wrong data type representation in Python `('a':'39')` ??

Answer (score 2):

You can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary.  Later matching keys overwrite earlier ones.  Also `dict` is a really bad name as it hides the `dict` class type:

```
>>> D = {'a' : '87', 'b': '72', 'a' : '39', 'b' : '84'}
>>> D
{'b': '84', 'a': '39'}
```

If you store your data as pairs in a list, however:

```
>>> L=[('a','87'), ('b', '72'), ('a','39'), ('b','84')]
>>> L
[('a', '87'), ('b', '72'), ('a', '39'), ('b', '84')]
```

A `defaultdict` creates its default type for non-existent keys, so `D[k]` below will be zero if the key is not yet present:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> D = defaultdict(int)
>>> for k,v in L:
...   D[k] += int(v)
...
>>> D
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'b': 156, 'a': 126})
>>> dict(D)
{'b': 156, 'a': 126}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, in Python, as far as I know, there is no data type representation as this:

`[('a' : '87'), ('b': '72'), ('a' : '39'), ('b' : '84')]`,

Probably, you were referring to a `dict`, which you cannot have with dulplicate keys by the way.

This answer will be very similar to @Mark Tolonen's answer, except for using only primitive data types without module:

```
>>> a = [('a','87'), ('b','72'), ('a','39'), ('b','84')]
>>> d = {}
>>> 
>>> for k,v in a:
        #if k already exists in d, just add up the values
        if k in d:
            d[k] += int(v)
        #otherwise, create a (k,int(v)) pair in the dict
        else:
            d[k] = int(v)


>>> d
{'a': 126, 'b': 156}
```